# Selenium crawling HTTP Error 403: ModSecurity Action when using wget

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to scrape images from a website. I managed to get the links of images but when I download images using wget I kept on getting the HTTP Error 403: ModSecurity Action

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import wget
import time
import os
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver-path')
url = ("https://www.ancuong.com/vi/san-pham/san-pham-chinh/van-mfc--cac-loai-van-phu-melamine/melamine-phu-tren-mdf-melamine-mdf/page-woodgrain.html")
driver.get(url)

n = 0
while n <= 1500:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {})".format(n))
    n+=200
    time.sleep(0.1)

images = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'load-done'))
        )

imgLinks = []
for image in images:
  imdLink = image.get_attribute('src') 
  imgLinks.append(imgLink)

print(imgLinks)
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()

path = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(path, "an-cuong-images")
os.mkdir(path)
counter = 0
for imgLink in imgLinks:
    save_as = os.path.join(path, "an-cuong-plywood" + str(counter) + '.jpg')
    wget.download(imgLink, save_as)
    counter += 1
```

The error I got is

```
    File "D:\Jobs\dream\scrape info\scrape image- python\selenium_crawling.py", line 43, in <module>
    wget.download(imgLink, save_as)
  File "C:\Users\My Lap\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: ModSecurity Action
```

How can I fix this problem. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you access the log files? It would be fine to see the error log, which rule blocked your request. Without the logs, try to dump your request, and compare with a regular (I mean from a browser) request.

Answer (score 0):

ModSecurity is an open source, cross-platform web application firewall (WAF) module. https://modsecurity.org/about.html

So whenever you see the 403 (ModSecurity Action), this means that the mod security firewall has blocked the request. The usual causes of this are:

- Malicious payload injection
- URL posted as parameter
- JavaScript attribute violation
- Any other cross-site scripting (XSS) attempts

Here, you are passing a custom generated URL (Safe because you know, you created it!) as a parameter; which in the rule book is a classic example of payload injection. To bypass it, try a different approach where you don't use URL as a parameter.

Comment: ModSecurity is "just" an engine. It does not protect anything without a rule set, like CRS. Generally, protect the application against the attacks on your list, the engine MUST HAVE a good rule set, like CRS.

That's why I wrote above my previous comment: the OP needs to know the reason. That would be a missing header, a wrong User-Agent, or many other cause.

Comment: @airween so how can I figure out what is the reason, can you help me please!

Comment: @dreamcatcher as I wrote in my first comment, make a regular request from browser, catch the request with the inspector. Then dump the built request from Selenium, and compared them.